# to get records between yesterday's 3pm to today's 3pm sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause, clause

I have a table with a datetime column, and I extract the records using a select statement, I m not sure with the 'where' part where I want only records from yesterday's 3pm to today's 3pm sql server. Please help.

Comment: read about `between`

Comment: ya thanks Jens, but I'm not sure about the time part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GETDATE()` to get today and `GETDATE() - 1` to get yesterdays date.
Then you can remove the time part and add 15 hours i.e. to get 3pm to both the dates.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN DATEADD(hh,15,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()-1),0))
AND DATEADD(hh,15,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

Comment: Thanks I tweaked the logic and got it working for me as well.I had to get documents modified between 7am to 3pm today.

SELECT *
FROM workorder
WHERE 1=1
and statusdate BETWEEN DATEADD(hh,7,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0))
and DATEADD(hh,15,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0))

Answer (score 0):

**DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE())** : Gives you last date

**DATEADD(HOUR,.....)** : Will add 15 hours (required 3:00 PM, so added 15 hour)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM TableName E
WHERE 
E.BirthDate>=DATEADD(HOUR,15, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE()) AS Date) AS datetime))
AND E.BirthDate<=DATEADD(HOUR,15, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) AS datetime))
```

Comment: consider explaining your code for the benefit of others, there is some complexity there.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to specify Date with time, you have to specify the datetime literal in [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

ISO 8601 is supported by SQLServer 2000 onwards.

ISO 8601 standard for datetime is: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnn[Z]`

```
CREATE TABLE #testingTime(a int, timeofinsert datetime)
INSERT INTO #testingTime
values (1, '2016-09-28T17:05:00'),
(2,'2016-09-29T14:05:00'),
(3,'2016-09-29T18:05:00')

SELECT * FROM #testingTime WHERE timeofinsert 
> '2016-09-28T15:00:00' AND timeofinsert < ='2016-09-29T15:00:00'
```

For your specific question for yesterday and today 3PM. you can use the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE #testingTime(a int, timeofinsert datetime)
INSERT INTO #testingTime
values (1, '2016-09-27T17:05:00'),
(2,'2016-09-28T14:05:00'),
(3,'2016-09-28T18:05:00')


DECLARE @yesterday3PM datetime = convert(varchar(10),convert(date,getdate()-1)) + 'T15:00:00'
DECLARE @today3PM datetime = convert(varchar(10),convert(date,getdate())) + 'T15:00:00'

select @yesterday3PM, @today3PM
SELECT * FROM #testingTime WHERE timeofinsert 
> @yesterday3PM AND timeofinsert < = @today3PM
```